# get acf fields from php file

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I put this code into my functions.php

```
include_once('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php');
include_once('acf-options-page/acf-options-page.php');
include_once('acf-repeater/acf-repeater.php');
define( 'ACF_LITE', true );

if(function_exists("register_field_group"))
{

    register_field_group(array (
        'id' => 'acf_options',
        'title' => 'Options',
        'fields' => array (
            array (
                'key' => 'field_525d1b6d49043',
                'label' => 'lable',
                'name' => 'homepage',
                'type' => 'repeater',
                'instructions' => 'Select which categories you want to display on the homepage.',
                'sub_fields' => array (
                    array (
                        'key' => 'field_525d1b8a49044',
                        'label' => 'Category',
                        'name' => 'firsttext',
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'column_width' => '',
                        'field_type' => 'text',
                        'return_format' => 'id',
                    ),
                    array (
                        'key' => 'field_525d2473de72c',
                        'label' => 'Number of Posts',
                        'name' => 'number-of-posts',
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'column_width' => '',
                        'default_value' => 4,
                        'placeholder' => '',
                        'prepend' => '',
                        'append' => '',
                        'min' => 2,
                        'max' => '',
                        'step' => 2,
                    ),
                ),
                'row_min' => 1,
                'row_limit' => 1,
                'layout' => 'row',
                'button_label' => 'Add a category',
            ),


        ),
        'location' => array (
            array (
                array (
                    'param' => 'options_page',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value' => 'acf-options',
                    'order_no' => 0,
                    'group_no' => 0,
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'options' => array (
            'position' => 'normal',
            'layout' => 'no_box',
            'hide_on_screen' => array (
            ),
        ),
        'menu_order' => 0,
    ));
}
```

Then I enter values into fields in admin console

How I cat get this value from page file?

I try get_field('acf_options) and I try get_field('homepage), but this return null

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you would want to put this in your function.php file instead of just do this this through the plugin.

But if you want to retrieve those field values, you should do this: `get_field( 'homepage', 'option' );`
instead of:
`get_field( 'homepage' )` or `get_field( 'acf_options' )`;

My best advice would be to look on the ACF [website](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/) for information. These docs help out a lot!

Comment: Your anwer reslove my problem

Thank u!